# PDF File cannot show EPS figures

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps

everybody.
I'm using TexStudio to write a research paper by my MacBook. The figures in my paper are in EPS format.
The build & compile configure in TexStudio is shown in the following figure:
[image]

An example is given below:
[image]

Only the captions are shown in the PDF, the figures themselves cannot be viewed. 
Anybody can tell me why and how to show these EPS figures?

Comment: I do not know TeXStudio, and therefore do not know if this profile is correct. But to have .eps figures in a final .pdf, you have to compile via eps-output. So you have to run DVIPs, followed by Ghostscripts ps2pdf to get the correct output.

Comment: Or convert the files first

Comment: How old is your TeX distribution? If it's TeX Live, did you install it using the MacTeX package? Would please give a complete minimal example so we can see your preamble.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Herb Schulz @ Martin Schröder。Thanks, I list a example in the following figure:屏幕快照 2017-02-26 下午6.55.06

Comment: Do you have the wrong path? In your picture I see `etc/query/...`.  Maybe it's `etc/Query/...`

Comment: You cannot include eps images with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @Johannes_B: That's not correct. See https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#news section 9.1.7 2010: It was a big change in 2010: pdf(LA )TEX now automatically converts a requested Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) file to PDF, via the epstopdf package, when and if the LATEX graphics.cfg configuration file is loaded, and PDF is being output.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel That applies if the file ending is omitted. The user here wants to load `image.eps` which will fail.

Comment: @Johannes_B : that's not true. First, don't include the epstopdf package or include it after including the graphics package. Second, pdflatex will use a restricted form of epstopdf to covert file.eps to file-EPA-converted-to.pdf and then will include that. You can use the .eps extension in the includegraphics command. Question: is the folder containing the .eps images writable?

Comment: @ Herb Schulz my Tex version is mactex-basictex-20161009.

Comment: @Marco Daniel  The path is right.